Why does the right border of the first sticky column disappear when scrolling horizontally in my table?
I have a table where I've applied sticky positioning to the first column using the following CSS:
th:first-child,
td:first-child {
    position: -webkit-sticky; /* for Safari */
    position: sticky;
    z-index: 1;
    left: 0;
    background: #fff;
}

While this successfully makes the first column sticky, I encounter a problem when scrolling horizontally: the right border of the first column disappears. How can I resolve this issue?
Here's my HTML and CSS setup for reference:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <style>
        * {
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        .table-container {
            overflow: auto;
            border: solid;
            margin: auto;
        }

        table {
            width: 100%;
            table-layout: fixed;
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }

        th,
        td {
            width: 20%;
            border: 1px solid #ddd;
            padding: 8px;
            text-align: left;
        }

        th:first-child,
        td:first-child {
            position: -webkit-sticky; /* for Safari */
            position: sticky;
            z-index: 1;
            left: 0;
            background: #fff;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="table-container">
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Column 1</th>
                    <th>Column 2</th>
                    <th>Column 3</th>
                    <th>Column 4</th>
                    <th>Column 5</th>
                    <th>Column 6</th>
                    <th>Column 7</th>
                    <th>Column 8</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Data 1</td>
                    <td>Data 2</td>
                    <td>Data 3</td>
                    <td>Data 4</td>
                    <td>Data 5</td>
                    <td>Data 6</td>
                    <td>Data 7</td>
                    <td>Data 8</td>
                </tr>
                <!-- More rows as needed -->
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>

How can I ensure that the right border of the first sticky column remains visible when I scroll horizontally through the table?

I have no real solution, but if you replace: border-collapse: collapse; by border-collapse: separate; border-spacing: 0;, you get a 2 pixel wide border, and a 1 pixel border left when you scroll horizontally. I guess that when you collapse the table border the browser chooses which borders to draw, and which not.

You can try using pseudo element, add the following CSS
I think this makes the trick
th:first-child::after,
td:first-child::after {
  content: " ";
  background: #ddd;
  width: 1px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: -8px;
}



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <style>
        * {
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
    
        .table-container {
            overflow: auto;
            border: solid;
            margin: auto;
        }

        table {
            width: 100%;
            min-width: 900px;            
            table-layout: fixed;
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }

        th,
        td {
            width: 20%;
            border: 1px solid #ddd;
            padding: 8px;
            text-align: left;
        }
        th:first-child,
        td:first-child {
            position: -webkit-sticky; /* for Safari */
            position: sticky;
            left: 0;
            z-index: 1;
            background: #fff;
            border-right: unset;            
        }
        th:first-child::after,
        td:first-child::after {
            content: " ";
            background: #ddd;
            width: 1px;
            height: 100%;
            position: absolute;
            right: 0;
            top: -8px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="table-container">
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Column 1</th>
                    <th>Column 2</th>
                    <th>Column 3</th>
                    <th>Column 4</th>
                    <th>Column 5</th>
                    <th>Column 6</th>
                    <th>Column 7</th>
                    <th>Column 8</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Data 1</td>
                    <td>Data 2</td>
                    <td>Data 3</td>
                    <td>Data 4</td>
                    <td>Data 5</td>
                    <td>Data 6</td>
                    <td>Data 7</td>
                    <td>Data 8</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Data 1</td>
                    <td>Data 2</td>
                    <td>Data 3</td>
                    <td>Data 4</td>
                    <td>Data 5</td>
                    <td>Data 6</td>
                    <td>Data 7</td>
                    <td>Data 8</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Data 1</td>
                    <td>Data 2</td>
                    <td>Data 3</td>
                    <td>Data 4</td>
                    <td>Data 5</td>
                    <td>Data 6</td>
                    <td>Data 7</td>
                    <td>Data 8</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Data 1</td>
                    <td>Data 2</td>
                    <td>Data 3</td>
                    <td>Data 4</td>
                    <td>Data 5</td>
                    <td>Data 6</td>
                    <td>Data 7</td>
                    <td>Data 8</td>
                </tr>                <tr>
                    <td>Data 1</td>
                    <td>Data 2</td>
                    <td>Data 3</td>
                    <td>Data 4</td>
                    <td>Data 5</td>
                    <td>Data 6</td>
                    <td>Data 7</td>
                    <td>Data 8</td>
                </tr>
                
                <!-- More rows as needed -->
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>




You just need to change border-collapse: collapse; into border-collapse: separate;.


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <style>
        * {
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        .table-container {
            overflow: auto;
            border: solid;
            margin: auto;
        }

        table {
            width: 200%;
            table-layout: fixed;
            border-collapse: separate;
        }

        th,
        td {
            width: 20%;
            border: 1px solid #ddd;
            padding: 8px;
            text-align: left;
        }

        th:first-child,
        td:first-child {
            position: -webkit-sticky; /* for Safari */
            position: sticky;
            z-index: 1;
            left: 0;
            background: #fff;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="table-container">
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Column 1</th>
                    <th>Column 2</th>
                    <th>Column 3</th>
                    <th>Column 4</th>
                    <th>Column 5</th>
                    <th>Column 6</th>
                    <th>Column 7</th>
                    <th>Column 8</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Data 1</td>
                    <td>Data 2</td>
                    <td>Data 3</td>
                    <td>Data 4</td>
                    <td>Data 5</td>
                    <td>Data 6</td>
                    <td>Data 7</td>
                    <td>Data 8</td>
                </tr>
                <!-- More rows as needed -->
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>



